# Laravel with PostgreSQL in sslmode

Tags: postgresql, laravel, amazon-rds

I'm working on a project using AWS, hosted on an EC2 instance with a RDS PostgreSQL. I'm wanting to make use of SSL encryption between my server and database, something [AWS RDS supports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html?sc_ichannel=em&sc_icountry=global&sc_icampaigntype=launch&sc_icampaign=EM_122133280&sc_idetail=371636727&ref_=pe_411040_122133280_10#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL) but I can't figure out how to configure Laravel to make it work. Is there a way to specify `sslmode` when configuring a database connections?

Comment: There is a semicolon missing on line #42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a missing feature in Laravel 4, but I have submitted a pull request to fix this.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5488 (was merged on 2014-09-08)

To patch the code just add the following snippet to the `getDsn` function in the PostgresConnector.php file.

```
if (isset($config['sslmode']))
{
    $dsn .= ";sslmode={$sslmode}";
}
```

After that you may specify `sslmode = 'require'` in the pgsql database config section to test the encryption between the web app and your database. Other possible values for sslmode are `'disable'`, `'allow'`, `'prefer'`, `'require'`, `'verify-ca'`, `'verify-full'`. The default value is `'prefer'`.

For further info check the PostgreSQL docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-ssl.html

Comment: Using this solution, how exactly do I point to the certificate?

Comment: Note: the recommended value is 'verify-full', not 'require', which is the same as 'verify-ca'

Comment: @RobertMennell did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to tune your `pg_hba.conf` on your PostgreSQL server
2. Generate server and client certificates
3. Store your client certificates to Laravel server
4. edit pgsql section at `config/database.php`, check my gist https://gist.github.com/tigusigalpa/2d1ec6e258ed96221abf9679622d274a

Answer (score 1):

Change your Laravel configuration regrading to the official [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-ssl.html):

[image: see this screenshot: Postgres SSL support options]

change your postgres config in config/database.php to

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'), <-- CHANGE THIS
],
```

and add the new option to your .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=mytestdb
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DB_SSLMODE=disable  <-- ADD THIS
```